# Runtime error in Scikit-learn during import

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, scikit-learn, pycharm

I am new to Python. So, sorry in advance if this sounds silly but I couldn't find an understandable solution in the forum. I am trying to run my programs in Pycharm and recently changed it from Python 3.5 to Python 2.7.12. After doing so I have started getting the below error while importing from Scikit-learn:

```
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/__check_build/__init__.py", line 46, in <module>
    raise_build_error(e)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/__check_build/__init__.py", line 41, in raise_build_error
    %s""" % (e, local_dir, ''.join(dir_content).strip(), msg))
ImportError: dynamic module does not define init function (init_check_build)
___________________________________________________________________________
Contents of /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/__check_build:
__init__.py               __init__.pyc              _check_build.so
setup.py                  setup.pyc
___________________________________________________________________________
It seems that scikit-learn has not been built correctly.

If you have installed scikit-learn from source, please do not forget
to build the package before using it: run `python setup.py install` or
`make` in the source directory.

If you have used an installer, please check that it is suited for your
Python version, your operating system and your platform.

Process finished with exit code 1
```

I am using Pycharm IDE - 2016.1, Mac OS, Python 2.7.12. Please let me know how do I get around this.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're still running out of `lib/python2.7/site-packages/`, per your error message. You need to configure your interpreter to use Anaconda for Python 3. If you've installed Anaconda correctly, you should be able to go to Settings -> NameOfYourProject -> Project Interpreter. Change the Interpreter to point to your Anaconda 3.x stack.

Also, make sure you download/install Anaconda 3.x (not just Python). Anaconda 3 comes with the Python 3 interpreter, so you'll just need to install the most recent version and you should be able to find it in the Pycharm drop down.

Comment: yes I have tried all that but Python 3 has scipy and since I am using an implemented project as a library which is implemented in Python 2.7, it is causing problems and throwing runtime error. So I have switched to Canopy IDE with Python 2.7.

Comment: Thanks for the help anyway.